# Sum from random list in python

Tags: python, list, random, sum, zero

I have created a random list of 60 numbers, I don't know the numbers contained in the list. I'm asked to find any combination of three numbers from the list that sum to zero. What can I do?
That's my code:

```
import random
import itertools
result = []

for x in range (-30, 30):
   num = random.randint(-30, 30)
   while num in result:
     num = random.randint(-30, 30)
     result.append(num)
        result = [seq for i in range(len(result), 0, -1) for seq in itertools.combinations(result, i) if sum(seq) == 0]
print result
```

Comment: What are your attempts so far?

Comment: Please include the code that you have already tried. (How the list is made, what you have already tried to make them add.)

Comment: My sum code is not here as it was not working!

Comment: Posting code that isn't working is sort of the point of stackoverflow. We can look at it and tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: Please take care to [format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so that code displays as code.

Comment: Since `result` is initially empty and you never add anything to it outside of the while loop, the code in `while num in result:` will never be reached. All your code does is generate 60 random numbers, discards each one in turn, and then prints an empty list at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function `combinations` in `itertools` and it can be used to generate combinations.

```
import random
import itertools
# Generate a random list of 30 numbers
mylist = random.sample(range(-50,50), 30)

combins = itertools.combinations(mylist, 3)
interested = list(filter(lambda combin: sum(combin) == 0, combins))
print(interested)
```

Note that the results from `filter()` and `itertools.combinations()` are iterables and `list()` is needed to convert the iterable to a list.

lambda expression `lambda combin: sum(combin) == 0` is used to keep the combinations which the sum is zero from `combins`

`itertools.combinations()`:
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

`filter()`:
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=filter#filter

Comment: :)
The list is generated randomly so the list `interested` may be empty if lucky enough. Then re-run the script.

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose of demonstration I'll define a particular example value for `result` that we can test with and see what happens.

```
result = [1, 2, -2, -3, 4]
```

You can use `itertools.combinations` to list all combinations of three numbers.

```
import itertools

>>> list(itertools.combinations(result, 3))
[(1, 2, -2),
 (1, 2, -3),
 (1, 2, 4),
 (1, -2, -3),
 (1, -2, 4),
 (1, -3, 4),
 (2, -2, -3),
 (2, -2, 4),
 (2, -3, 4),
 (-2, -3, 4)]
```

And you can use `filter` with `lambda c: sum(c) == 0` as the predicate to select combinations that sum to zero.

```
>> list(filter(lambda c: sum(c) == 0, itertools.combinations(result, 3)))
[(1, 2, -3)]
```

Comment: I don't know the numbers in the list! what can I do?

Comment: What do you mean? Why do you need to know them?

Comment: You use numbers 1, 2, -2 etc. i don't know the numbers from my list

Comment: I defined `result` to be a particular set of numbers for the purpose of showing you an example of what happens. But the code works for any set of numbers, not just for the example.

Comment: I just added my code above, what can I do to get any combination from the list i created, that sums to zero?

Comment: The code you posted defines a variable called `result` that contains a list of numbers. The expression at the end of my answer, `list(filter(lambda c: sum(c) == 0, itertools.combinations(result, 3)))`, is the combinations from that list that sum to zero.